How to make session time out when the tab is closed in react js?
I tried to set session time out in my website.. like after specific period of time that session should end for security purpose and redirect that particular user again to the login page.
I tried session time out for user inactivity like if the user opens my website in the browser but if that user is not active in that website means then the session will end. I did this by setting event listener of mouse and keypad.
But I am struggling to set this session time out even though the user closed that tab. Like we experience in every website, suppose if we open and close a website and reopen it the next day means it will redirect to the login page.  I tried this functionality on my website but continuously I am facing issues.
I already tried the below methods:
1.By checking the status of the tab either it is open or close, based on the events such as window. onbeforeunload ().
2.By the way of calculation, like finding the difference between the current_time and lastarrival_time, comparing that difference with the expire session time out limit like 10 minutes. If that difference time exceeds that session expire time, then the session will end else it keeps that user as in logged in state.
3.Tried to change the expire time in AWS Cognito App client expire time like refresh token, access token and id token expiration time to 5 minutes to check that after expiration of that session to navigate that user to logged in page. To integrate this AWS Cognito expire session with my website need "Auth" module to import in my code but  it does not support in the website. It always throw error like "unfound module named Auth in the aws-amplify module" even after installing it.

The second approach is what all websites use. You set a "keepalive" probe, telling that the session is alive (it means, in your website to send a request automatically each X minutes with just a "im alive" command) and you should check the last time a "im alive" command was sent. If you are facing issues, you should post which issues you are facing and some minimal, reproducible example (not the full code): https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Are you taking care of removing cookies when you initiate the end of session? By default, session variables and cookies last until the user closes the browser, but it can be set differently

where is login session is maintained - is verified in server side or client side?
